# Error in creating new BearerStrategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to use OAuth2orize and for the API endpoints employ BearerStrategy as mentioned in the [example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/tree/master/examples/express2) in Git. The code is as follows

```
passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
  function(accessToken, done){
    accessTokens.find(accesstoken, function(err, token){
      if (err) {return done(err);}
      if (!token) {return done(null, false); }

      users.find(token.user_id, function(err, user){
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false); }

        var info = { scope: '*' }
        done(null, user, info);
      });
    });
  }
));
```

And I am getting following error when I try to start:

```
/Users/saransh2012/Developer/vypics/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:51
  if (!name) throw new Error('authentication strategies must have a name');
                   ^
Error: authentication strategies must have a name
    at Passport.use (/Users/saransh2012/Developer/vypics/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:51:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saransh2012/Developer/vypics/android_app/auth.js:54:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/saransh2012/Developer/vypics/android_app/app.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

In the same file I am also doing New BasicStrategy and that's working, but still this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an empty object as the first argument to the constructor of BearerStrategy. i.e

```
new BearerStrategy(
  { }, // <-- the first argument should be an empty object
  function(accessToken, done){
    accessTokens.find(accesstoken, function(err, token){
      if (err) {return done(err);}
      if (!token) {return done(null, false); }

      users.find(token.user_id, function(err, user){
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false); }

        var info = { scope: '*' }
        done(null, user, info);
      });
    });
  }
)
```